# C# PInvoke - Function returning char* and with reference char* parameter

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have the following header and CPP:

**"Utils.h"**

```
__declspec(dllexport) static char* GetRamMegabytes(char* &FreeMemory);
```

**"Utils.cpp"**

```
char* Utils::HardWare::GetRamMegabytes(char*  &FreeMemory)
 {
    char*  TotalMb = "";
    MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
    statex.dwLength = sizeof(statex);
    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);
    float freeMemFloat = ((float)statex.ullAvailPhys/1024/1024);
    float value =((float)statex.ullTotalPhys/1024/1024);
    sprintf(FreeMemory,"%f",value);
    sprintf(TotalMb,"%f",freeMemFloat);
    return TotalMb;
 }
```

I have my DLL compiled and I'm trying to make a PInvoke from C# with the following code:

```
[DllImport("LndNativeAssembly.dll", EntryPoint = "?GetRamMegabytes@HardWare@Utils@@SAPADAAPAD@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetRamMegaBytes(IntPtr freemem);
```

I'm trying to call the native function using:

```
IntPtr free = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr res = GetRamMegaBytes(free);
```

And I get this error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: `FreeMemory` needs to be passed in with space already allocated and you need to allocate `TotalMb`, assigning it to `""` is useless. Also instead of returning a value through a paramater and a return statement have you considered returning a custom struct and adding an accompanying free method.

Comment: There are 3 serious bugs in this code.  Do favor the .NET class that gives you this exact same info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.computerinfo.aspx

Comment: Again I repeat. This is about HOW invoking a native DLL. Not about how to do it with .NET. I KNOW .Net give you that information.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with pinvoke.  You'll need to learn C programming.

Comment: @CarlosLande I believe what they are saying is you need lean more about C and C++ before trying to complicate things with P/Invoke. This would of been easier to resolve if you were doing straight C or C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is writing to unallocated memory.

```
sprintf(TotalMb,"%f",freeMemFloat);
```

You can either allocate memory using new in the routine and free it in the caller, or you can have a fixed buffer in the routine (not thread-safe).

Comment: Why are you returning two similar values in two different ways?  Why not pass in two buffers?

Comment: Because I wanted to know how to pInvoke it this way :)

Comment: Im learning c++, only been here a week . Could you give me an example of how should it be done?. Best way possible

Comment: Better is to use strings.  Does it have to be char*?

Comment: No stark. I really prefer to use std::string but I got errors in the pInvoke

Answer (score 2):

This is because Free is the target in which the function is trying to write, and you are passing **NULL**, that results in a GPF. The problem is how you wrote the PInvole signature. Try with:

```
public static extern IntPtr GetRamMegaBytes(StringBuilder freemem);
```

and pass a created string builder to the function.

Comment: I got the same Error--> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.